# File chunked, get length bytes

Tags: java, android

In the example below, splitting works fine. Each chunk is 98 bytes long. But how do you know how many characters each part actually had? Thank for help !

```
int chunksize = 98;
int start = 0;
byte[][] packets = new byte[totalChunks][chunksize];

for(int i = 0; i < packets.length; i++) {
    packets[i] = Arrays.copyOfRange(dataInBytes,start, start + chunksize);
    start += chunksize;
}
```

Comment: the code is error-prone. Arrays.copyOfRange fills `null` if not enough byte in the source array. but throws if `start + chunksize` >= dataInBytes.length

Comment: I have a problem with the last part when it is shorter than 98, how to write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int chunksize = 98;
int start = 0;
int end = chunksize;
byte[][] packets = new byte[totalChunks][];


for(int i = 0; i < packets.length; i++) {
    if ( end > dataInBytes.length ) end = dataInBytes.length
    packets[i] = Arrays.copyOfRange(dataInBytes,start, end);
    start += chunksize;
    end += chunksize
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/unicode.html

Each character will take 2 bytes in JAVA.

However, for some situations, you may need 4 bytes to represent a character (e.g. japanese Kanji)

So the answer is: it depends.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [length()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#length()).

```java
int charCount = new String(packet[i], StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length();
```